# How to get text field value from another class Java

Tags: java

I am doing a login screen in my program.

I have one class for the inputs and another one for the database queries.

Main class:

```
@FXML private JFXTextField userField;

public String getUsername() {
        user = userField.getText();
        return user;
}
public void Conexion() throws SQLException {
        dbQuerys conexion = new dbQuerys();
        conexion.Login();
    }
@FXML
    void loadSecond(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, SQLException {
    Conexion();
}
```

Database class:

```
loginController login = new loginController();

public void Login() throws SQLException {
        username = login.getUsername();
        System.out.println(username);
        resultado = conexion.getQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = username");
    }
```

For some reason its not working, when I press the login button (For now I just want to check the username in the db) it says null pointer exception so if you can please tell me what Im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a Context-class with static variables.

Like:

```
Public class Context{

public static String username;

}
```

Which you then can edit from any class with:

```
Context.username;
```

Comment: Yes I can do this but the variable will stay empty even when I type something in the text field and asign the value of the text field to that variable. I need to change the value of the variable when I type something in the text field, and then when I call that variable from another class I need it with the value I asigned to it throught the text field.